# iterate over all elements of a list of tuples with lists

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples (that again consists of lists) and would like to to check how many of the elements of the first list in the tuple is in the second list of the tuple.

```
names =[
 ([''],['aa']),
 (['aa', 'bb'],['aa']),
 (['cc'],['cc', 'dd', 'yy']),
 (['xx', 'ss'],['xx', 'ss']),
 ]
```

so for the above I would like to get a list

```
[0, 1, 1, 2]
```

because '' is not in ['aa'}, 'aa' is in ['aa'], 'cc' is in ['cc', 'dd', 'yy'] and 'xx' and 'ss' are in ['xx', 'ss'].
Is there a way to do this without for loops?

Comment: `[set(x[0]) & set(x[1]) != set() for x in names]`

Comment: Can you please say why you don't want to use a for loop?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question so that the output is not boolean but integer

Comment: @corianne1234 you need at least one `for loop` to go thru all the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the elements in the intersection of the two:

```
[len(set(first) & set(second)) for (first, second) in names]
# [0, 1, 1, 2]
```

Note that this is still a for-loop, just written as a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Without for loop, mapping:

```
result = list(map(lambda tup: sum(map(lambda elem1: elem1 in tup[1], tup[0])), names))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2]
```

The following code is the simplification of the above mapping code to understand and debug:

```
for tup in names:
    print(f"Tuple: {tup}")
    bool_values = map(lambda elem1: elem1 in tup[1], tup[0]) # check for each element in the first list if it is in the second list
    bool_values = list(bool_values)  # make iterable
    print(f"Boolean Values: {bool_values}")
    count = sum(bool_values) 
    print(f"Count: {count}")
```

Output:

```
Tuple: ([''], ['aa'])
Boolean Values: [False]
Count: 0
Tuple: (['aa', 'bb'], ['aa'])
Boolean Values: [True, False]
Count: 1
Tuple: (['cc'], ['cc', 'dd', 'yy'])
Boolean Values: [True]
Count: 1
Tuple: (['xx', 'ss'], ['xx', 'ss'])
Boolean Values: [True, True]
Count: 2
```